# Sorting an arraylist of hashmap according to a value field of the hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, sorting

Basically, I have an arraylist declared like :

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = 
                             new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

now what I want to do is that for each key I want to give two value fields. Can it be done??

Secondly I want to sort the key-value pair according to the value pair. So how can it be achieved?

Comment: did you read the Map and Collection documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of `String` objects.  Have you considered encapsulating your data structure using an `Object`, rather than a complex collection of strings?  For example, assuming your map key is a song:

```
public Song implements Comparable<Song> {
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;

    public Song(String title, String artist, String album) {
       ...
    }

    public int compareTo(Song s) {
        // sorting logic
    }

    ... // getters, setters, equals & hashCode
}
```

Then, create your list of songs:

```
List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
songs.add(new Song("Dancing Queen", "Abba", "Arrival"); // I had to find this on Wikipedia
...
```

Then sort them:

```
Collections.sort(songs);
```

Comment: I agree on this. I would also suggest to implement equals() and hashcode() to properly store/retrieve instances in standard collections.

Comment: So is that the Collections.sort() calls the compareTo() of the user-defined class for the sorting approach?

Comment: Yes.  Look at the Comparable interface.  Also of interest is the Comparator interface, which externalises the sorting logic.

Comment: Okay..!! Thanx a lot David... it was really helpful... Though I was looking for something that could take away the pain of creating a class... but I guess it is inevitable. Anyways, it will be a structure of my own so it is ought to be easy later on. :)

Comment: @Saurabh - creating a class is not painful.  In fact, you will experience more pain for longer if you try to use Maps to avoid creating custom classes.

Comment: @Stephen C - yeah true... It got easier but is there a way I can get all the data of one field of all objects so that I can feed it into an adapter?

Comment: @Saurabh just loop and call the getter.  If this becomes inefficient, worry about it then.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the comparable interface for the sorting problem of yours. And for having multiple values for a value in a map, create a class with the required values with getters and setters. And use the class as a value against the key.